# Are there any issues in creating OrientDB cluster with nodes having dynamic IP Addresses?

Tags: orientdb

I was going through a presentation on SlideShare about [**OrientDB Distributed Architecture with Multi-Master Approach**](http://www.slideshare.net/lvca/orientdb-distributed-architecture-11). It is mentioned there on slide no. 31 & 32 that unique **Op-id with format <node>#<serial>** like 192.168.0.10:2424#123232 to know the operation used to know the operation missed.

If the IP address is used in Op-id, then can it cause issues if one node goes down and comes back up in the cluster in which the IP addresses are dynamic? If the IP addresses are dynamic there is no guarantee of Op-id being unique.

Are there any other things in **OrientDB** which work on the basis of IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from OrientDB v1.6 the node id is auto-generated, so this problem doesn't exist anymore.